# How to restore the ACEDrawingLabelView object after encoding and decoding in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, restore, decoding

In iOS, We use ACEDrawingView library for drawing purpose. We need to encode/decode the ACEDrawingView Tool objects. For that we use `encodeWithCoder()` and `initWithCoder()` methods. But objects are not properly encode.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
[aCoder encodeFloat:self.lineAlpha forKey:@"lineAlpha"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.lineColor forKey:@"lineColor"];
[aCoder encodeFloat:self.lineWidth forKey:@"lineWidth"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.drawingView forKey:@"drawingView"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.labelView forKey:@"ACEDrawinglabelView"];
}

 -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
if(self = [super init]){
    self.lineColor = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"lineColor"];
    self.lineAlpha = [aDecoder decodeFloatForKey:@"lineAlpha"];
    self.lineWidth = [aDecoder decodeFloatForKey:@"lineWidth"];
    self.drawingView = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"drawingView"];
    self.labelView = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ACEDrawinglabelView"];
}
```

After using the above methods we are able to get the labelView but we are not able to get the subViews. Please refer the below screen shots.

[Before encoding the ACEDrawingLabelView object we can see all its properties along with its subViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQNkr.png)

[After encoding and again decoding the object some of the properties of the object are lost and also the subViews are missing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcElc.png)

What else can we do to get the object restored along with its properties and its subviews?